# Stuck finding a recursive recurrence relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am analyzing the following algorithm:

```
QUANT(n):
 if n == 0 or n == 1:
  return 1
 else
  return (n-1)*QUANT(n-1) + n
```

I need to find the recurrence relation of this algorithm and prove it using mathematical induction. Here is what I have tried so far:

$$a_0 = 1, a_1 = 1, a_n = (n-1)*a_{n-1} + n$$
$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_1 = 1$$
$$a_2 = 1 + 2 = 3$$
$$a_3 = (2)(3) + 3 = 9$$
$$a_4 = (3)(9) + 4 = 31$$
$$a_5 = (4)(31) + 5 = 129$$

Also tried backwards substitution:

$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_1 = 1$$
$$a_2 = (n-1) + n = 2n - 1$$
$$a_3 = (n-1)(2(n-1)-1) + n = 2n^2 -4n + 3$$
$$a_4 = (n-1)(2(n-1)^2-2(n-1)+1)+n=2n^3-10n^2+10n-1$$
$$a_5 = (n-1)(2(n-1)^3-4(n-1)^2+4(n-1)-1)+n=2n^4-18n^3+52n^2-58n+23$$

I am having trouble finding a pattern. For the backwards one I can detect some things like the first term is always $2n^{n-1}$, all the powers of $n$ are expressed. Please point out what concept of series I am missing to find the pattern, if there is one.

Comment: What you've done with "backwards substitution" can't be done. $a_2$ is defined for $n=2$. You can't then compute $a_3$ with the same $2n-1$ when $n=2$.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A111063

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right. I'll fix the post once I finish calculating.

Comment: Without the $+n$ you have $a_n=(n-1)!$. Do you see that? That is a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the recurrence:
$$
a_{n + 1} = n a_n + n + 1 \quad a_0 = 1
$$
This is a non-homogeneous linear first order recurrence. If you have:
$$
x_{n + 1} - u_n x_n = f_n
$$
Dividing by $u_n \ldots u_0$ gives:
$$
\frac{x_{n + 1}}{u_n \ldots u_0} - \frac{x_n}{u_{n - 1} \ldots u_0} 
   = \frac{f_n}{u_n \ldots u_0}
$$
This is easy to sum:
$$
\frac{x_n}{u_{n - 1} \ldots u_0} = x_0
                    + \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{f_k}{u_k \ldots u_0}
$$
In our case $u_n = n$, $f_n = n + 1$. To avoid division by 0, better start at index 1. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_n}{(n - 1)!} &= \frac{a_1}{0!} 
                   + \sum_{1 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{k + 1}{(k + 1)!} \\
a_n           &= (n - 1)! + (n - 1)! \sum_{1 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{1}{k!} \\
              &= (n - 1)! \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{1}{k!}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks! Brain malfunction, post fixed (brain presumably still broken).

Comment: I read this and I definetly lack the knowledge to understand it. Can you include more explanation or specify the methods used?

Comment: @cRaZiRiCaN, please check again. I fixed a few dumb mistakes.

Comment: @cRaZiRiCaN, it is just the name of the form of the equation for $x_n$ I give next. The method is just the equations as written. I _might_ be off somewhere, please check each step.

Comment: Whats the reasoning for dividing by the u terms? Does the notation of the u terms mean they are multiplied by each other?  After dividing by the u terms how did you get the next equation?

Comment: @cRaZiRiCaN, $u_n \ldots u_0 = \prod_{0 \le k \le n} u_k$; by dividing you get terms that telescope when adding up. The very first term is $\dfrac{x_1}{u_0} -\dfrac{u_0 x_0}{u_0} = \dfrac{x_1}{u_0} - x_0$, then $\dfrac{x_2}{u_1 u_0} - \dfrac{u_1 x_1}{u_1 u_0} = \dfrac{x_2}{u_1 u_0} - \dfrac{x_1}{u_0}$, and so on.